# Does Android need a default layout file called activity_main.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm an Android noob and I'm having difficulty finding out something basic about Android.

- I currently have an activity_main.xml file.
- I want to use this layout when I first start the Android emulator, using Android Studio
- Does Android look for a file activity_main.xml and use it as the default layout?

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

So I understand that this specifies that my .MainActivity will respond to an action.MAIN intent call. What I don't know is what the action.MAIN intent call actually is, and how my activity_main.xml relates to this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Can anyone provide an explanation or a link to a good primer that explains these basic concepts?

Comment: The Manifest shows you the MainActivity is the root activity that starts when the app is called. Then the class MainActivity starts. --> lifecycle:
http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Android_Logcat-Activity-Starts.jpg

OnCreate is called. In oncreate youve got setContentView(...). That refers to the xml...

intent filter with <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> means that ony the app itself can start it. Some actitivies can be started by other apps just to know.

Comment: OK, I see now where the layout is set thanks. So you're saying that the intent android.intent.action.MAIN is an intent that gets issued when the app is called?

Comment: it just declares who is allowed to open the app. For example: Some apps implement google maps. so you can start GM from an other app.

Comment: "Each intent filter is defined by an <intent-filter> element in the app's manifest file, nested in the corresponding app component (such as an <activity> element). Inside the <intent-filter>, you can specify the type of intents to accept using one or more of these three elements..."
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From manifest :

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Means this activity is the entry point of the application. In your case, the `MainActivity` starts.

The `MainActivity` sets up the layout for itself - the line responsible is

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Where it looks for layout file `activity_main.xml`. This is just the naming convention - feel free to rename the layout file and call the new one from `setContentView`. It's not required to be called `activity_main`